# Why my answer is deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How is evolution possible in contemporary humans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-is-evolution-possible-in-contemporary-humans)

Is it wrong?

I mean normally males in most species evolve by mating with more females and breed more children. The reason why it doesn't happen to rich humans is because laws that get in the way.

So where is the mistake in my answer?

I sort of knew that the answer will be censored. But is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It was flagged as being offensive, and I agreed with that. This site is not the right place to post your pet theories.

Comment: You mean all those rules government make do not affect evolution on humans? Never mind.

Comment: It would be nice if people points out if the answer is right or wrong instead of "offensive". Offensive is scientifically irrelevant.

Comment: @JimThio There was no scientific basis to that answer at all.

Comment: @JimThio also, had you actually done any research you would have discovered that poor people tend to have many many more children than the rich.